# Regex - replace end of line, not string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, foxpro

I am slowly building a FoxPro to C# conversion and replacing common FoxPro syntax to now work in C#.

```
'If' becomes 'if (' 

'Else' becomes '} else {'

'Endif' becomes '}'
```

Now I need to be able to identify the end of a line on an `If` statement so I can close it with `) {`. How can I accomplish this via regex/jquery?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m3fj443/7/)

Comment: Programming languages are extremely non-regular and I would not attempt to parse them myself with a regular expression if I were you. Lucky for you there are several parser-generators out there you can check out that will let you declare rules that make this task a lot easier- it won't be easy but it will be much more doable.

Comment: I understand they are non regular, but I'll be working on this project for a very long time and I need to convert a lot of FoxPro code that is becoming more regular to replace. Not saying this will work for everyone, but I've come to follow the previous programmer's logic and what I've written so far is working well. I just need to replace the end of an 'if' line, not string.

Comment: Something like [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/) will eat this sort of conversion for breakfast and you'll be done within a day. You're free to write whatever code you want of course - just figured it would help to be familiar with these tools :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you are a regular expression that will work

`/^If([^$\n\r]+)(?:$|\r\n)/gim`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu70fogj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a line starting with "if" is easy: /^if/

now you need a function to replace those lines with itself+'){'.

Answer (score 0):

This may be messier than the answers above, but this is how I fixed it.
http://jsfiddle.net/9m3fj443/10/

```
// close statements now that vocab is switched
                var lines = output.split('\n');
                var newoutput = '';
                $.each(lines, function(ind, val){

                    if(val.indexOf('if (') > -1)
                        val += '<span class="syntax">) {</span>';

                    // add back line break to keep tidy
                    newoutput += val + '\n'
                });
```

Comment: Don't forget that ; is the line continuation character.  You might want to preprocess the text to remove those first.